# Filters works only in the first page and when i click to second page data displayed with no filter at all

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-server-2008, filter, pagination

**The Problem is filters only works in the first page .. and it disappear in second page..
so in the first page the result was a lot of data based on selected(Dropdown) filter and when we moved to second page the result turned to default with no Filter at all**

I tried to keep the value of filter select dropdown using this :

```
<option value="<?=isset($_POST['nama_area']) ? $_POST['nama_area'] : ''?>"><?=isset($_POST['nama_area']) ? $_POST['nama_area'] : ''?></option>
```

But it still disappear in next page .. and I tried using `isset($_REQUEST['nama_area])` and still same..
I think there's something wrong in my code  ..
some people said i have to use session so the filter will set in next page and some others said use Method GET so i can take from URL . and i tried Method GET and the URLin the first page was like below :

> http://myweb.com/myWebControl/GT/index?tgl_awal=01-05-2021&tgl_akhir=02-05-2021&nm_dist=&nama_area=Aceh

and when I clicked next page all filter in the URL are gone

> http://myweb.com/myWebControl/GT/index/2

I don't know what should I do . Should I try using session ? If yes can someone provide me some example of how to use session for filtering data .

**THIS IS MY FORM FILTER**

```
      <div class="x_content">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <form method="GET" action="<?php echo base_url('GT');?>" >
      <div class="panel">
      <a class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingZero" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseZero" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="padding: 3px;">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Visit Date</h4>
      </a>
      <div id="collapseZero" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingZero">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="awal" name="tgl_awal" class="form-control tgl_awal" value="<?=isset($_REQUEST['tgl_awal']) ? $_REQUEST['tgl_awal'] : ''?>">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="akhir" name="tgl_akhir" class="form-control tgl_akhir"  value="<?=isset($_REQUEST['tgl_akhir']) ? $_REQUEST['tgl_akhir'] : ''?>">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <a class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="padding: 3px;">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Distributor and Area</h4>
      </a>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div >
            <select class="form-control nm_dist" name="nm_dist" style="width: 100%;">
              <option value="<?php set_value('nm_dist')?>"><?=isset($_REQUEST['nm_dist']) ? $_REQUEST['nm_dist'] : ''?></option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control nama_area" name="nama_area" style="width: 100%;" >
              <option value="<?=isset($_POST['nama_area']) ? $_POST['nama_area'] : ''?>"><?=isset($_POST['nama_area']) ? $_POST['nama_area'] : ''?></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**THIS IS MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function index(){
  $kdjabat = $this->Get_kodejabatan->get_kd_jbt();
  foreach($kdjabat->result_array() as $hasil){
    $kode_jabatan = trim($hasil['Kd_Jbt']);
    $nm_jabatan = trim($hasil['Nm_Jbt']);
  }
  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'GT/index';
  $config['per_page'] = 1;
  $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
  $config['use_global_url_suffix'] = TRUE;
  $from = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
  if($from<=0){ $from = 1;};
  $row_start=($from-1)*$config['per_page'];
  $row_end=$row_start+$config['per_page'];
  $b="";
  if(($kode_jabatan == "IT") || ($kode_jabatan == "BOD")){
    $b="";
  }else{
    $b="and a.KD_DIST in (select Kd_Dist from asssfajbtfdist where Kd_Jbt='$kode_jabatan')";
  }
  $data['excel'] = $this->m_visitgt->datavisitgt($row_start,$row_end,$b);
  $config['total_rows'] = $data['excel']['sql']->num_rows();
  if($data['excel']['query']->num_rows()>0){
    foreach ($data['excel']['query']->result_array() as $row){
      $tgl_rkm = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['TGL_RKM']));
      $kode_mds = $row['KODE_MDS'];
    }
    $data['tbl'] = $this->m_visitgt->datatbl($tgl_rkm,$kode_mds);
    foreach ($data['tbl'] as $key){
      $data['Total_Customer']=$key['total_customer'];
      $data['Visited']=($key['visited'])+($key['activity']);
      $data['Unvisited']=$key['unvisited'];
      $data['Notvisited']=$key['notvisited'];
      $data['NOO']=$key['noo'];
      $data['ACT']=$key['activity'];
      $data['EC']=$key['ec'];
      $data['ExtraCall']=$key['extra_call'];
      $data['CallRPS']=$key['call_rps'];
    }
  }
  $config['first_link']       = 'First';
  $config['last_link']        = 'Last';
  $config['next_link']        = 'Next';
  $config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
  $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="pagging text-center"><nav><ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';
  $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></nav></div>';
  $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
  $config['num_tag_close']    = '</span></li>';
  $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">';
  $config['cur_tag_close']    = '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>';
  $config['next_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
  $config['next_tagl_close']  = '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></span></li>';
  $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
  $config['prev_tagl_close']  = '</span>Next</li>';
  $config['first_tag_open']   = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
  $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</span></li>';
  $config['last_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
  $config['last_tagl_close']  = '</span></li>';
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $data['content'] = 'tempelates/GT/Visit_GT';
  $this->load->view('tempelate', $data,$config);
}
```

**AND THIS IS MY MODEL**

```
public function datavisitgt($limit,$offset,$b)
{
  $tgl_awal = $this->input->get('tgl_awal');
  $date_awal    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl_awal));
  $tgl_akhir    = $this->input->get('tgl_akhir');
  $date_akhir = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl_akhir));
  $nama_mds     = $this->input->get('nama_mds');
  $nama_pt  = $this->input->get('nama_pt');
  $nama_area    = $this->input->get('nama_area');
  $nm_dist  = $this->input->get('nm_dist');
  $t1='';$t2='';$t3=''; $t33=''; $t4='';$t44=''; $t5=''; $t6='';$t5a='';
  if($tgl_awal!="" && $tgl_akhir!="" ){$t1="and a.tgl_rkm between '$date_awal' and '$date_akhir'";}
  elseif($nm_dist!=""){$t3="and a.nm_dist='$nm_dist'";}
  elseif($nama_mds!=""){$t4=" and a.nama_mds='$nama_mds'";}
  elseif($nama_pt!=""){$t5=" and d.NAMA_PT='$nama_pt'";$t5a="and CONVERT(VARCHAR,b.KETERANGAN)='$nama_pt'";}
  elseif($nama_area!=""){$t6=" and a.NAMA_AREA='$nama_area'";
  }else{
    $currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
    $t1='';$t2='';$t3=''; $t33=''; $t4=''; $t5=''; $t6='';$t5a='';
    $t1=" and a.tgl_rkm='$currentdate'";
  }
  $sql = "
  select * from (select a.TGL_RKM, c.KD_DIST,e.nm_dist,a.KODE_MDS,c.nama_mds,f.NAMA_AREA,h.NAMA_SGRUP,i.NAMA_GRUP 
  from assrkmh a 
  inner join assrkmd b on b.KODE_MDS=a.KODE_MDS and a.TGL_RKM=b.TGL_RKM 
  inner join assmds c on c.KODE_MDS=b.KODE_MDS 
  inner join asscus d on d.KODE_CUS=b.KODE_CUS 
  inner join assdistributor e on e.KD_DIST=c.KD_DIST
  inner join asssalesarea f on f.KODE_AREA=e.KD_DIST 
  inner join asssalesman g on g.KODE_SLS=c.KODE_MDS
  inner join asssgrupsls h on h.KODE_SGRUP=g.KODE_SGRUP
  inner join assgrupsls i on i.KODE_GRUP=h.KODE_GRUP 
  where b.CHECK_IN is not null and c.TIPE_MDS='1' $t5
  group by a.TGL_RKM, c.KD_DIST,e.nm_dist,a.KODE_MDS,c.nama_mds,f.NAMA_AREA,h.NAMA_SGRUP,i.NAMA_GRUP
  union 
  select a.TGL_RKM, c.KD_DIST,e.nm_dist,a.KODE_MDS,c.nama_mds,f.NAMA_AREA,h.NAMA_SGRUP,i.NAMA_GRUP  
  from assrkmh a 
  inner join assrkmdactivity b on b.KODE_MDS=a.KODE_MDS 
  and a.TGL_RKM=b.TGL_RKM 
  inner join assmds c on c.KODE_MDS=b.KODE_MDS 
  inner join assdistributor e on e.KD_DIST=c.KD_DIST
  inner join asssalesarea f on f.KODE_AREA=e.KD_DIST
  inner join asssalesman g on g.KODE_SLS=c.KODE_MDS
  inner join asssgrupsls h on h.KODE_SGRUP=g.KODE_SGRUP
  inner join assgrupsls i on i.KODE_GRUP=h.KODE_GRUP  
  where b.CHECK_IN is not null and c.TIPE_MDS='1' $t5a
  group by a.TGL_RKM, c.KD_DIST,e.nm_dist,a.KODE_MDS,c.nama_mds,f.NAMA_AREA,h.NAMA_SGRUP,i.NAMA_GRUP)a 
  where 1=1 $b
  $t1 $t3 $t4  $t6";
  $sql1 = "SELECT c.* FROM ( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order BY TGL_RKM) AS RowID,dt.* from 
  ($sql)as dt ) AS c WHERE c.RowID > $limit AND c.RowID <= $offset";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql1);
  return array(
    'query' =>$query,
    'sql' => $this->db->query($sql),
    't1' => $t1,
    't3' => $t3,
    't4' => $t4,
    't5' => $t5,
    't6' => $t6,
    'b' => $b
  );
}
```